# Pig: Create new column based off of two other columns

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, bigdata

I'm wondering if it's possible to do something like this is in pig:

There are three columns:

A "type1","type2","type3"

B   101  ,  159  ,  74

I want to define columns C as such:

If A == "type1" then C = B; else C = 0

Is this possible in pig?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. You would write it as below:

```
data = LOAD '$dataSource' using AvroStorage();
-- data = {A, B}

data2 = FOREACH data
           GENERATE
               A,
               B,
               (A == 'type1' ? B : 0) AS C;

dump data2;
```